# Trigger an Excel macro, using Outlook VBA, to read email content

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I wrote an Outlook macro to call an Excel macro to read the target email content and write it to an Excel sheet.

Target email comes in --> Excel macro searches email in Outlook --> return content to Excel

The Excel macro runs successfully if it is triggered manually on Excel.
When the macro is triggered through Outlook VBA, it can only read the email content up to row 251.

In Outlook, I tried to trigger the Excel macro like below:

```
'Debug.Print "Opening excel file"
Set Wb = XlAPP.Workbooks.Open(File)
Set Ws = Wb.Sheets("Read Me")
Ws.Activate

'Debug.Print "Run Macro"
Wb.Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Wb.Application.Run "Module1.getDataFromOutlook"
```

In excel, I check how many rows in the email content like below:

```
        'split email content into rows
        Content = item.Body
        'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        Debug.Print Len(Content)
        Lines = Split(Content, vbCrLf)
```

My Excel macro Debug.Print result.
[image]

Comment: The Immediate window only shows the last 200 lines or so:   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5c2a83cf-0596-41a2-9f42-e64cc6b1e556/immediate-window-memory-limitation?forum=accessdev#:~:text=The%20capacity%20appears,to%20change%20this.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any limitations when dealing with message bodies. See [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) for more information on Excel limits.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

It is not clear from your lines of code published there why there is a difference there. You need to publish the full code from the `getDataFromOutlook` sub to get any valuable feedback.